# Oracle Data Adapter in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, oracle11g

I am connecting Visual Studio 2012(c#) with Oracle 11g. I have succesfully executed the queries where no join property is needed. But here's a query which I want to run using natural join :

```
comm.CommandText = "select * from friends natural join customer where username='"+username+"' or frnd_username ='"+username+"'";
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, conn);
        da.Fill(ds, "customer");
        dt = ds.Tables["customer"];
```

I am getting an error in the

```
 da.Fill(ds, "customer");
```

statement, I think this is because I am trying to fill the data set with the customer table instead of friends natural join customer.
but I tried that also,

```
da.Fill(ds, "friends natural join customer");
```

still I am getting an error.

The error I get is "OracleExceptionUnhandled". It says

```
External component has thrown an exception.
```

I realize that you get this error when the query gives an error in SQL, but i executed this query in SQL, It worked just fine.

I tried changing the query, and it executed fine without the natural join, I am pretty sure that the error has something to do with the table with which I am filling the data set.

Can anyone suggest what should i write in the bracket.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what is the error that you get.

Comment: There should be an inner exception that you are getting which should tell you more information.

Comment: `External component has thrown an exception.` still tells us nothing. Keep going deeper. There has to be some sort of usable error message.

Comment: @gunr2171 , I tried to find more elaboration on the error but that's the maximum I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query with Inner/Left join and still problem persist then contact your DBA.

This is actually a database issue. Each time I get this error I simply check my query in sql editor and if it works fine then I contact DBA.

Answer (score 0):

This error could be because of - If any SQL returns no rows, or any other schema does not exist or any variable became null and used for further computation